Christmas movie where woman gets kicked out of her apartment and spends Christmas with the man who kicked her out
I watched this movie a few years ago on christmas eve. it was a romantic comedy with a bit of a drama.
it's about a woman who gets kicked out of her apartment from a man. I don't know if that man was the landlord or her laywer or something like that ... I think the reason that she gets kicked out is because she didn't pay her rent - but I'm not really sure.
Anyways ... it's Christmas time and the woman doesn't have any place to go so she ends up spending Christmas with "that man" who vistis his family for the Holidays .. so they all spend Christmas together and at the end of the movie the man and the woman fall in love.
Unfortunately I don't really remember the actors. The man was tall and had dark hair. And the woman had dark long hair too and I'm pretty sure she had some red strands in her hair ..
does anybody know the name of this movie??

There are a few films that fit the criteria:
Christmas Snow

A shop owner who is being evicted at Christmas rescues her Scrooge-like landlord from an accident. 


A Christmas Romance

A widowed mother with financial woes comes to the aid of a bill collector who crashes his car in a snowstorm. 


Or, every other Christmas movie on the Hallmark channel.
